# iOS correct comparison of file paths

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

I have an issue in an application I'm writing where I need to compare one NSURL that points to a file and an NSString, which is an incoming string representation of the same file path.

I can't get them to compare – the output I'm given when NSLogging is confusing, perhaps it is a encoding issue?

I can make them look the same with this code: `[urlString stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];`

The raw output for the NSURL is:
`file:///var/mobile/Applications/F14AFBD8-FF60-4094-8BBD-7AC2477E0B20/Documents/1.%20AKTIV%20SA%CC%88LJFOLDER/Sa%CC%88ljfolder2014-SP1.pdf`

And for the NSString:
`/var/mobile/Applications/F14AFBD8-FF60-4094-8BBD-7AC2477E0B20/Documents/1. AKTIV SÄLJFOLDER/Säljfolder2014-SP1.pdf`

If I run stringByRemovingPercentEncoding on the NSURL it *looks* the same, but they don't compare.

If I run `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` to the  NSString I get `file:///var/mobile/Applications/F14AFBD8-FF60-4094-8BBD-7AC2477E0B20/Documents/nestle/1.%20AKTIV%20S%C3%84LJFOLDER/S%C3%A4ljfolder2014-SP1.pdf`

Note that the percentages is not the same on the urls. I have tried so many things, changing encodings etc. but can't find a way to solve this.

---

#### Edit

So, I tried the `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` as follows:
`NSLog(@"EQUAL? :%hhd", [[strippedUrlString precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping] isEqualToString:[filePath precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping]]);` – returns 0

I logged the strings and got

`/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/C05E0885-7B58-4B2F-A6B4-D9388E60462C/Documents/1. AKTIV SÄLJFOLDER/Säljfolder2014-SP1.pdf`
with `NSLog(@"Precompose url 1: %@", [strippedUrlString precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping]);`

for the first string and

`/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0/Applications/C05E0885-7B58-4B2F-A6B4-D9388E60462C/Documents/1.%20AKTIV%20SA%CC%88LJFOLDER/Sa%CC%88ljfolder2014-SP1.pdf`
with `NSLog(@"Precompose file 1: %@", [filePath precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping]);`

for the second.

Tried same code, but with `precomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping` and got exactly the same result :(

Comment: does the URL in your code have the file:// as prefix? if yes, they won't be the same.

Comment: Thanks, but I've also tried adding the file:// prefix to the NSString and comparing, and also stripped the file:// from the URL – but still not able to compare them :(

Comment: How are you trying to compare them, can you post the code?

Comment: I've tried lots of compare methods, but it seems like the strings don't match: 
`[filePath isEqualToString:[document.fileURL absolutePath]]`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you ran in a problem that in Unicode equivalent strings are not always binary equal.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence

You have

1. `…SA%CC%88…`:
   This is the problem.
   It means: We have an "A" and a combining diaeresis -> Ä. The diaeresis is the 0xCC88, which is UTF-8 for Unicode 0x0308 (COMBINING DIAERESIS). So the Ä is encoded as an A with an combining diaeresis.
2. `…S%C3%84…`:
   This is easy.  0xC384 is UTF-8 for 0x00C4 that means A-Umlaut -> Ä

First of all: What is the source of the first string?

Addition: You can use `precomposedStringWith…Mapping` (`NSString`).

BTW: You can compare strings without diacritic marks using `-compare:withOptions:` et al. with the option `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch`. In this case, I assume, string 1 equals string 2. Butt it would equal an "A", too, what is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) The first string is unarchived from a plist. So – exactly how can I go about comparing these two strings if they are binary unequal? I got the compare method to work, but as you said it works, but can of course lead to problems.

Comment: Look at my addition: There are some precompose…/decompose… methods that should work. They do some normalization. If they do not work, please report here.

Comment: Hi again an thanks. I'm afraid I got the same output, at least when NsLogging it. I tried both `precomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping`, `decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping`, `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` and `decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please add the results of your attempts to your Q. A saw a legion of men saying "I tried …". It is better to show *exactly* what you tried with which result.

Comment: :-( Did you try decomposing? (same selectors, but a "de" instead of the "pre" at the beginning.)

Comment: Tried that as well I'm afraid :(

Comment: *BOING* Me stoopid. Of course you have to remove the percent escapes first with – stringByRemovingPercentEncoding et al.